# Matching default views of 3D Asymptote graphics

Tags: asymptote

One can compile a 3D image in Asymptote without .prc content as a .pdf that is viewable in any .pdf reader (using the `-noprc` command line option). This views the 3D image from a certain viewpoint, set by a command such as `currentprojection=orthographic(4,4,10);`. Let's call this "View 1" of the image.

One can also produce just the .prc file. If one wants to embed a rotatable 3D image into another .pdf file, one needs this .prc file for use with the `\includemedia` command of the `media9` package. The manual for `media9` recommends getting the default view of this rotatable image by using Adobe's `Get Default View`, which supplies code that one can copy/paste into the `\includemedia` command. Call this view "View 2."

My questions are these: Why are View 1 and View 2 different? Is there a systematic way to provide code for `\includemedia` that matches the default view that Asymptote gives via the .asy file (i.e., View 1), other than trial & error?

Comment: Could you provide an example ? Perhaps that it is due to the automatic camera adjust. Another way to include prc is `asy -inlineimage cube -render=4 -tex pdflatex` (see the `externalprc.tex` file in the documentation) then `\input cube.tex` does the job.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I realize now that my understanding of `Get Default View` was incorrect. I thought it generated a view based on the viewpoint settings in the .asy file; instead, it takes the perspective the user has created in the .pdf at that moment then zooms to fit the picture in the window.

Comment: I tried your "currentprojection" and it did not work:  10:24 AM Thu Oct 29$ asy -noprc input-1.asy 
input-1.asy: 9.19: no matching variable 'orthographic'

Comment: Never mind my comment. I forgot the instruction "import three". Thanks.